# Scaling polygons in QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3

I want to scale, rotate, and move a polygon in a shapefile in QGIS 3.6 to align it with some other features. There are Rotate and Move tools in the Advanced Digitizing Tools but no Scale tool. After searching and reading, I found the v.transform tool but it seems to scale based on the CRS origin and not the center of the polygon. So, when I scale using the v.transform tool, it moves the polygon a long distance away from its original position, and I then have to shift it back near its original position again using the v.transform tool or the Translate tool. The scaling I need to do is sort of an iterative process, and it becomes very tedious if I have to scale and then shift multiple times. Is there an easy way to scale a polygon around its center using the v.transform tool or is there another tool that will accomplish this?

Comment: The geo-tool Edit> Parallel Curve does not suit you?

Comment: I could find no Parallel Curve tool under Edit (QGIS 3.6). I did find an Offset Curve, but it does not keep the same exact shape, and it seems to only work for a single polygon. In my case I have several adjacent polygons that I need to scale all at the same time to keep them adjacent.

Comment: Try the `geometry by expression` tool with the `translate($geometry,dx,dy)` function.